# Why am I getting "Error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token."

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error and I don't know what I'm missing. This is only my first programming class, so it could be something really simple that I'm not seeing. Help? :)

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

const float METERS_PER_INCH = 39.3700787;
const float METERS_PER_FOOT = 3.2808399;
const float METERS_PER_YARD = 1.09361; 

int main ()
{
    int yards;
    int feet;
    int inches; 
    int totalMeters;

    cout << "Enter a length in meters: "; 
    cin >> totalMeters; 
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The total length is " << endl; 
    << totalMeters * METERS_PER_YARD << "yards;"
    << yards * METERS_PER_FOOT << "feet;" 
    << feet * METERS_PER_INCH << "inches;" 
    << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a semi-colon after `endl;` for the 'total length' and no new `cout` before `<<`.  You also don't set `yards` or `feet` before you try printing values derived from them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last part of your comment? (Clearly, I'm new at this. Ha)

Comment: What value is assigned to `yards`?  Answer: no value.  Therefore printing `yards * METERS_PER_FOOT` is going to print an indeterminate (quasi-random) value.  Ditto for `feet`.  And you don't even use the variable `inches`.

Comment: Assignment: Input a length in meters so that the output is yards, feet, and inches. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You're doing a lot of output with a single statement spread across several lines. That's perfectly valid, but another approach is to write one statement per line, so each line begins with `cout <<` and ends with a semicolon. If you're going to do it in a single multi-line statements, I suggest indenting the 2nd and successive lines so it's clearer what's going on; I'd probably align the initial `<<` on each line with the one above it.

Comment: Mostly right - you just haven't quite connected all the dots.  Maybe: `yards = totalMeters * METERS_PER_YARD; yards = totalMeters * METERS_PER_FOOT; inches = totalMeters * METERS_PER_INCH;` and use the variables (without multiplication) in the printing operations.  Or replace `yards` with `totalMeters` and replace `feet` with `totalMeters` in the current format - and drop the variables (`yards`, `feet`, `inches`) altogether.

Comment: Okay, I get that now, no big deal But now it's giving me another error message: [Warning] converting to 'int'from 'float'.

Comment: That's a valid complaint; you are converting from `float` to `int` if you assign to the variables.  There are several ways around that: (1) use `float` instead of `int` for the inputs (probably a good idea — or even use `double` instead of `float` throughout), or (2) use a cast in the assignments.  I'd suggest changing the variables to `double` (the constants too).

Answer (score 2):

Change your last `cout` to:

```
cout << "The total length is " << endl
<<  totalMeters * METERS_PER_YARD << "yards;"
<< yards * METERS_PER_FOOT << "feet;" 
<< feet * METERS_PER_INCH << "inches;" 
<< endl;
```

The difference is the `;` removed after the first `endl`.

With the semicolon there, the first line of the `cout` is a statement on its own, so the compiler looks for a new statement on the next line. Statements cannot just start with `<<` because it's a binary operator - it expects an expression on its left-hand-side as well.

Comment: That's the immediate syntactic problem.  There's also the deeper problem of printing values based on uninitialized variables.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, the OPs' code has other problems for sure. I was just trying to directly answer his question